# Finding and classifying all groups of order 12

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I was working on classifying all the groups of order 12. I dug around at some of the previous questions here and while they address the idea, none of them were entirely satisfactory:

[Classifying groups of order 12.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410651/classifying-groups-of-order-12)
(doesn't explain how classification is derived)

[Group of order 12](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14754/group-of-order-12)
(doesn't address how to generate classification)

[Nonisomorphic groups of order 12.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683079/nonisomorphic-groups-of-order-12) (shows they aren't isomorphic, but doesn't actually show the derivation for the 4 groups listed)

So I wanted to ask, the specific question not yet presented, of how to derive that there must be 5 non isomorphic groups of order 12, and which groups those are.

### Work So Far:

To begin with we have $|G|=12= 2^2 \times 3$ for any group of order 12. Let $n_3$ be the number of sylow-3 subgroups and let $n_2$ be the number of sylow 2 subgroups. We have by the third sylow theorem that

$$n_3 | 4, n_3 \equiv 1 \mod 3$$
$$n_2 | 3, n_2 \equiv 1 \mod 2$$

So the groups can have either 1 or 4 sylow 3 subgroups of order 3, and either 1 or 3 sylow 2 subgroups of order 4.

Furthermore coprime sylow-p groups only share the identity element in common, so we can rule out 4 sylow-3 groups and 3 sylow-2 groups, as the presence of either rules out the existence of a single copy of the other.

Now we have established our groups must have a SINGLE sylow 2 subgroup, and a SINGLE sylow 3 subgroup, and that means that each is a normal subgroup of the entire group.

The sylow-2 subgroup can be either $\Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2$ or $\Bbb{Z}_4$. And the sylow-3 subgroup has a single contender $\Bbb{Z}_3$.

Naturally then we can list out two groups

$$\Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_3$$
$$\Bbb{Z}_4 \times \Bbb{Z}_3$$

But now the question remains, how to discover any remaining groups, and show that the remaining set covers all possible groups.a

Comment: [This paper](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/group12.pdf) discusses this.

Comment: Certainly it is helpful to check MSE for existing answers. But for a question like this you should read a paper; and I find the above link excellent.

Comment: This is a relatively small case, so I'm sure it is covered in many a textbook. I recall first reading about it from Baumslag & Chandler's book (Schaum Outline series).

Comment: You seem to be saying that a group of order $12$ must have a unique Sylow $2$-subgroup and a unique Sylow $3$-subgroup, but the dihedral group of order $12$ has $3$ Sylow $2$-subgroups and the alternating group of degree $4$ has $4$ Sylow $3$-subgroups.

Comment: My answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3194100/447318) gives a brisk but almost complete answer

Comment: You say "the presence of either rules out the existence of a single copy of the other." As if having 4 Sylow-3 subgroups somehow eats up so many elements that there is no room for even one Sylow-2 subgroup (of order 4). But that just isn't the case. 4 Sylow-3 subgroups accounts for $1+4(2)=9$ elements. That leaves 3 elements, which together with the identity could make a Sylow-2 subgroup.

Comment: The link by @CameronBuie seems to have broken. [This](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/group12.pdf) should work. (I think it's the same paper.)

Answer (score 0):

For the non-abelian ones:  By counting, one or the other Sylow subgroups is normal.

Now $P_3=\Bbb Z_3, P_2=\Bbb Z_4$ or $P_2=\Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_2$.

By the first observation, it easily follows that $G$ of order $12$ is a semi-direct product.

Either $G\cong \Bbb Z_3\rtimes \Bbb Z_4,$ or $\,G\cong \Bbb Z_3\rtimes (\Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_2)$, or $(\Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_2)\rtimes \Bbb Z_3$.

These groups are the dicyclic group of order $12$, $D_6$ and $A_4$.

---

The abelian groups are easy with the structure theorem: $$\Bbb Z_{12},\,\Bbb Z_6×\Bbb Z_2$$.

Answer (score -3):

A simple solution can be found in the book "Groups and symmetries by M.A Armstrong". It is given in the chapter sylow's theorem. you can download the book from-- http://bookzz.org/book/714875/11dbeb.